# Is there a way to reduce skew caused by few large y values in google line chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am creating a line chart using google charts with the code below

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    const datat = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    datat.addColumn("date", "Date");
    datat.addColumn("number", "New Users");
    datat.addColumn({'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip' , 'p': {'html': true}});


    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){

        datat.addRow([new Date(data[i]['year']), parseInt(data[i]['value']), "<div style='margin: 10px; font-size:1.1em;'>Date: " + data[i]['year'] + "<br>Users: " + parseInt(data[i]['value']) + "</div>"])

    }

    var options = {
        title: 'New Users Graph',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: { position: 'none' },
        titleY: "Users",
        titleX: "Date",
        tooltip: {isHtml: true}

    };


    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('users'));

    chart.draw(datat, options);
}
```

Because the value range is high we can see the small values are very hardly visible. Is there a way to prevent such skew? The only option i have figured out is to increase the height of the div. I have set the height to 500px, still the graph has massive skew. We cannot even exclude the outlier or the high values. Is there a way to make the graph look little more balanced so that all values are easily visible? Thanks for the insights.

[image]

Comment: Log scaling might be appropriate for your data. Or you can simply specify the max view value with vAxis: { viewWindow: { max: 50 } }

Comment: thanks i set min to 0 and max to 1000. that worked.